# I have written helper class on Opportunity and I used for loop inside for. So, I want to merge these loop

Tags: apex, trigger

Is there any way to avoid this from inside for?

```
public static void updateNewOppBasedOnOld(List<Opportunity> oppList){

    Set<Id> opportunityByIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity opp: oppList){
        opportunityByIds.add(opp.Id);
    }
    List<Opportunity> oppLists = [SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName, AccountId,Opportunityld__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Opportunityld__c IN: opportunityByIds];

    list<Opportunity> oppOldForUpdate = new list<Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity oppNew: oppList){
        for(Opportunity oppOld: oppLists){              
            Opportunity op = new Opportunity();
            op.Name = oppNew.Name;
            op.Id= oppOld.Id;
            op.CloseDate = oppNew.CloseDate;
            op.StageName = oppNew.StageName;
            op.AccountId = oppNew.AccountId;
            //op.Internship_Cycle__c = oppNew.Internship_Cycle__c;

            oppOldForUpdate.add(op);
        }
    }

    update oppOldForUpdate;

}
```

Comment: Would you mind changing you subject to something shorter that reflects the issue you are facing?

Comment: Cast the oppLists to a map, loop over the oppList and use map to get old value and update. Although if this is running in a trigger without filtering values not sure why you would want to do this as you would never be able to change the values you are setting in this code from the initial values

Comment: Thanks, @Eric! yes this running trigger, actually whenever the old opportunity will update, then I want to update the newer opportunity which is created by the reference of old opportunity.

logic is working with my code but I wanna filter out the code and want this logic will work without using "for inside for".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is unnecessary (like [@Eric](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200052/i-have-written-helper-class-on-opportunity-and-i-used-for-loop-inside-for-so-i#comment302319_200052) mentioned). Old records are records **before** you click on save button (or invoke DML operation). New records are just new versions (after button click or successful DML operation). You can find this in Salesforce documentation: [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm).

---

## Refactoring

Use `Trigger.oldMap` variable to your advantage. You won't need SOQL query and iteration to get old Opportunity Id's. It will simplify your method.

#### Opportunity Trigger

```
trigger MyOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after update) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        OpportunityService.updateNewOppBasedOnOld(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
}
```

#### OpportunityService

```
public static void updateNewOppBasedOnOld(List<Opportunity> newOpps, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOpps) {
    List<Opportunity> opportunitiesToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

    for (Opportunity newOpportunity : newOpps) {
        Opportunity oldOpportunity = oldOpps.get(newOpportunity.Id);

        Opportunity updatedOpp = new Opportunity(
                Id = oldOpportunity.Id,
                Name = newOpportunity.Name,
                AccountId = newOpportunity.AccountId,
                CloseDate = newOpportunity.CloseDate,
                StageName = newOpportunity.StageName
        );

        opportunitiesToUpdate.add(updatedOpp);
    }

    update opportunitiesToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michal Vavra, The reason I used SOQL query because of comparing the OLD opportunity Id (which I am storing into Opportunityld__c  text field whenever new opportunity created by the reference of OLD Opportunity) with new Opportunity.